# General Pointer issue

Tags: c++, pointers

I've tried the following:

```
std::string* Member::GetName()
{
    std::string name2 = "sdfsdfsd";
    return &name2;
}

std::string* name;
Member m;

name = m.GetName();

std::cout << *name  << std::endl;
```

and it "works", but shouldn't be name2 unavailable after GetName() is called? and my pointer points to nothing?

Edit:

Coming back after years with more exp.
some already answered this question below.

Returning a local is bad!, you might get away with it, if the value on the stack didn't get overwritten, so often when you directly use it after returning a local you might get the correct values, but this is still undefined behaviour.
Also not returning a const& also doesn't work, even now sometimes i think it binds the return value to a temporary as it does for const& parameters, but thats not the case for return types, the same goes for returning r-values refs.
you can only return a copy and get it as const ref like this

```
std::string GetName();

const std::string& name  = GetName();
```

this will bind it to a temporary therefore is valid check herb sutters gotw:
https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/
for const ref temporaries.

Comment: This really isn't safe

Comment: why does it even work?

Comment: It only *appears* to work in this limited context.

Comment: Cause you are lucky "this time". It's UB.

Comment: @Sleicreider - `why does it even work?`  It did "work".  Crashing would also "work",  running on your computer and crashing on someone else's would also "work".  That's what "undefined behavior" is all about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the address of a local stack variable and using it when it's no longer in scope it's **undefined behavior**.

As for "*it works*", it doesn't mean it will always work or that is a reliable practice. The stack isn't immediately wiped out when returning. Take a look at the definition of "[undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)"

Comment: well i would never write such code, I were just surprised why it gave me the right value, but thanks!